# Get Text after Quotes In Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

My sample text looks like this:

```
30","formatedMinDeliveryDate":null,"formatedMaxDeliveryDate":null,"actualDeliveryDate":null,"trackingNumber":"ID180135116580CN","shippmentTrackingUrl":"https:\u002F\u002Fwww.057872.m2749.l5119","localizedCurrency":null}},"actions":[{"label":"Leave feedback","icon":null,"value":null,"action":"link","actionParam":{"label":"LEAVE_FEEDBACK_FOR_SELLER","u
```

I want to get the number `ID180135116580CN` and I'm having trouble achieving this using regexp.

The file is full of them and I'm doing this

```rb
out_file = File.open('public/orders.txt').each do |line|

  p line[/(?<="trackingNumber":")[^"]*(?=")/]

end
```

but it only prints `nil` and doesn't extract the number I'm looking for.

Is the regexp wrong or do I need to traverse the file differently?

Basically after every `trackingNumber`, I want to get whatever is in quotes there after.

Thanks!

Edit:

Attempted this as per @WiktorStribiżew suggestion in the comments

```
p line.scan(/"trackingNumber"\s*:\s*"([^"]+)"/)
```

Now, I'm getting all of trackingNumbers as an array like this

```
[["UB08578YP"], ["UB085789YP"], ["ID180135791CN"], ["ID180135728CN"]]
```

How do I modify this to get them in individual lines like this?

```
UB08578YP
UB085789YP
ID180135791CN
ID180135728CN
```

Comment: Just to be clear, is that definitely an "unstructured" text file? You're not actually showing us a sample of some CSV, or JSON, or YAML, or whatever?

Comment: The regex is okay, however, the lookahead at the end is not needed: http://rubular.com/r/4GvHd3yCOT

Comment: Agree with @TomLord here the input looks maybe like a JSON or YAML format? In that case you should use a appropriate parser instead of regexp.

Comment: The input is basically the HTML of a website. Thanks guys @TomLord

Comment: For some reason, it only finds a random trackingNumber in the bunch and not any of the others ones that exist in the source file.

Comment: Maybe something with the encoding?

Comment: @wp78de maybe. I just want it to read it as a text file since going line by line should bring back every tracking number. I don't want to decode or encode anything since it's just an html and javascript blob. Suggestions?

Comment: Use `line.scan(/"trackingNumber"\s*:\s*"([^"]+)"/)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew wow thank you! One last thing if you could please assist thank you see edit to main post.

Comment: Wait, probably, you do not need that `scan`. Probably, you just need `line[/"trackingNumber"\s*:\s*"([^"]+)"/, 1]`. Is there always 1 match per line?

Comment: This looks like a partial segment of something. You should extract the complete JSON document, or wrangle this into one by adding some framing (e.g. "{...}") to make it parseable with `JSON.load`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that doesn't work it does the same exact thing as the one I started with where it only shows one occurrence. I'll probably mess with styling your original suggestion

Comment: @tadman the JSON parts of the page are everywhere and it would take too much maintenance. Want to build something quick that can get me the numbers when I paste the entire html

Comment: [Add `.flatten`](http://rextester.com/TFVA60988)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you're a beast. Create an answer so I can award it. That's really close to what I'm looking for and will do the job

Comment: Use a combination of HTML and JSON parser. Like Nokogiri.

Comment: I do not know how to answer it :) I am almost sure you can solve the problem using JSON, HTML and other parsers and you will use them one day invalidating this dirty regex hack. I'd stay away from answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it can be simpler if you read the file completely and run the scan there something like this

```
file_content = open("./my_file.txt").read
results = file_content.scan(/(?<="trackingNumber":")[^"]*(?=")/)
puts results
```

It will have them formated. in the way you want it.